# Array normal method and by using index 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, variables, indexing

```js
var mulitply = a*b;
var multiplyArray = [multiply]
```

Is this the same thing as down below?

```js
var myArray []
var multiply = a*b
var myArray[0] = multiply
```

Comment: What language is this supposed to be wrritten in? Is this Java? You didn't include the necessary tag. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26636298).

Comment: @sanitizedUser I am sorry, its in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the explaination below. Both code snippet will do the same.

```
var multiply= a*b;
var multiplyArray = [multiply]; // here we are initializing and assigning the array.


var myArray []; // Initialization
var multiply = a*b;
myArray[0] = multiply; //Assignment, Avoid using var again.
```